# file server in C doesn't continually return files when requested

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm new to network programming and recently finished reading through Beej's guide. I have a client/server program that I'm trying to get to continuously have the server return the contents of a file when the client requests it.

It works by the client sending the server a file path and the server reading it (if it exists) into a buffer then sending the buffer to the client which just prints the buffer.

It works, but it will only return one file then ignores any following requests. I have to shut down the client and reconnect again for it to work again. I can't figure out why. I've tried implementing `select()` and used `aio_read()` over the standard `read()` and I also forking a process for the `send()` function. Each of those those experiments had it working exactly the same pretty much.

Anyone have any tips? I'm at a loss where the problem could be.

**Client**

```
#define MAXDATASIZE 100  // max number of bytes at once
#define MAXMSG 25
#define MAXDATA 4096
#define SA struct sockaddr


// clean_str: make sure the string doesn't have junk spaces around it
void clean_str(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char tmp[MAXMSG] = {0};
    strncpy(tmp, s, len-1);
    memset(s, 0, len);
    strncpy(s, tmp, len-1);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char file_request[MAXMSG] = {0};
    char file_buf[MAXDATA];

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: client <hostname> <port>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    // load the struct
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // loop trhough all results and connect to the first one we can
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) < 0) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect");
            continue;
        }
        // if we make it here, we've got a connection
        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, (SA*)&p->ai_addr, s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    // stay connect until client exits
    int n;
    while (1) {
        // make sure everything is cleared to minimize issues
        memset(file_buf, 0, MAXDATA);  
        memset(file_request, 0, sizeof MAXMSG);
        numbytes = 0;
        // get client request from stdin
        int b = read(STDIN_FILENO, file_request, MAXMSG);
        if (b < 0) {
            perror("client: read");
        }

        clean_str(file_request);

        // send the request to the server
        if ((numbytes = send(sockfd, file_request, strlen(file_request), 0)) < 0) {
            perror("send");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // now we wait for a response
        while ((n = read(sockfd, file_buf, MAXDATA-1)) > 0)
            printf("%s\n", file_buf);
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("read");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Server**

```
#define PORT 3490
#define MAXDATA 4096
#define FILENAME 256
#define SA struct sockaddr      // for less messy casting

// get_file: open file, read contents info a buffer, return buffer
char *get_file(const char *path) {
    int n, bytes;
    static char buf[MAXDATA];

    // try to open file
    n = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (n < 0) {
        strcpy(buf, "problem opening file");
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        return buf;
    }

    // if exists, read it into buffer on
    bytes = read(n, buf, sizeof buf-1);
    if (bytes < 0) {
        strcpy(buf, "problem reading file");
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        return buf;
    }
    close(n);
    return buf;
}


int main()
{
    int sockfd, filefd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t len;
    int nbytes;
    char file_request[FILENAME];    // buf to hold client's request string

    // clear servaddr struct
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof servaddr);
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;  // IPv4 for simplicity
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);       // use my IP
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);    // short, network by order

    // create socket file descriptor
    // @param3 is the protocol. 0 means TCP
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // bind the socket to the PORT
    if (bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof servaddr) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // this prevents the 'bind: address already in use' issue
    int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof yes) < 0) {
        perror("setsocket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, 10) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    
    printf("server running and waiting for connection...\n");

    int open = 1; // keep track if there's an accepted() fd
    char *open_file;
    while (1) {
        // clear the file_request buffer
        memset(file_request, 0, FILENAME);
        memset(&open_file, 0, sizeof open_file);
        nbytes = 0;
        if (open) {
            // we're only going to connect to one client for now
            len = sizeof client_addr;
            filefd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&client_addr, &len);
            if (filefd < 0) {
                perror("accept");
                continue;
            } else {
                printf("connected to a client\n");
                open = 0; // keep track that there's an open fd
            }
        }
        
        // recieve data from a client
        if ((nbytes = recv(filefd, file_request, sizeof file_request, 0)) <= 0) {
            // got error or connection was closed by client
            if (nbytes == 0) {
                printf("file-server: client hung up\n");
                close(filefd);
                open = 1;
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("recv");
                close(filefd);
                open = 1;
                continue;
            }
            close(filefd);
        } else {
            // we got some data
            // manage it and get file contents
            open_file = get_file(file_request);
            if (strcmp(open_file, "0") == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (send(filefd, open_file, strlen(open_file), 0) < 0) {
                perror("send");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    close(sockfd); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memset(&open_file, 0, sizeof open_file);` seems a bit excessive when all you really need is `open_file ? NULL;`

Comment: You have to use a debugger to step through *both* the client and server code to make sure it works as intended.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oops! (maybe even worse; plus all the memset/bzero ...)

Comment: Note: your `clean_str()` function does *nothing*. (and it *could* potentially perform a buffer overflow)

Comment: Yup - at least two of the three usual suspects.  'printf("%s\n", file_buf);' when there is no guarantee that the bytes loaded are terminated/followed by a NUL, (initializing the buffer to zeros does not help if one read() call loads fewer bytes than the previous one).  'if ((nbytes = recv(filefd, file_request, sizeof file_request, 0)) <= 0) {' that call, if it returns a value >0, is not guaranteed to return a value >1because of the byte-streaming nature of TCP.  '// we got some data', yup, exactly, but how much?  'nbytes' could be 1, even if 100 bytes were sent.